# Receiving "Wrong Password" while trying to connect to Asterisk using SIP users

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, elastix

I followed all steps mentioned [here](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/205223520-UniFi-VoIP-Elastix-SIP-Configuration) to add SIP accounts on my Elastix server (A VoIP server). and based on the little square at the top right of following picture, I think I successfully added `user101` to the SIP users.

[image]

After that I tried to do login using *Zoiper* tool (a client tool for VoIP servers), but every time I received error:

[image]

So I checked the server:

[image]

As you see above, no SIP users added there, and I received *Wrong Password* error each time. Why?

Comment: Also show Zoiper config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click "Apply Config" then try again.

Comment: :| It's weird that the web interface need double confirm for user creation! I was clicked on the `submit` button on the form of user data, but it seems that the `Apply Config` is required too! Thank you.